# How many sequences is the most ever shown in a Game of Thrones intro?

Tags: game-of-thrones, production

I notice that the locations shown in *Game Of Thrones* opening title sequence change from episode to episode, presumably to reflect the locations of the major characters.

What's the most amount of locations ever shown in the opening sequence? Was it longer or did the other locations just get a shorter amount of screen-time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The most locations that ever appeared was six (6) and the animations are sped up or slowed down depending on the number shown.**

A grid was made for each location that appeared in each episode, [here](https://gameofthrones.fandom.com/wiki/Title_sequence).

There were three main rules explained by producer Greg Spence;

> First, as a rule, every episode's map must contain King's Landing, Winterfell, The Wall, and "wherever Daenerys is at the moment" - even if Daenerys does not appear in that episode.
>
> Second, they don't always have the time and resources to create specific animations for every minor location - thus the capital of a region is often used as a stand-in to represent the overall territory.
>
> Third, and perhaps most importantly, they can only show a limited number of locations in the 90 second duration of the opening sequence.